# No Ceylon runnable element

Tags: eclipse, ceylon

I try to use Ceylon, with Eclipse. I have installed the JDK. I have in my computer Java version 7 and 8.

The configuration of Eclipse looks good, I can see the Ceylon perspective, create project, I have a Ceylon file with

```
void hello() {
    print("hello world");
}
```

...but if i launch a program, I have a window error with "No ceylon runnable element"

To run I click on *Run as > Ceylon Java application*

I don't understand this error. What is the problem?

Answer (score 15):

Annotate it `shared`:

```
shared void hello() {
    print("hello world");
}
```

Your run configuration (*Run → Run Configurations...*) should look like this:

[image: run configuration]

Substitute your project/module/version/package.